# Option to disable tag hover popup

Tags: feature-request, tags, popups

I'd like an option to completely disable the tag-hover popup effect. I can easily hide it with Stylish

```
#tag-menu { display: none !important}
```

but it irritates me that the JS is still running.

If you can't/won't implement this can you at least give me the names of js-functions so I can greasemonkey them out of existence?