# Disable tag-popup

Tags: feature-request, tags

Is there any possibility (official or via Greasemonkey/stylish scripts) to disable the popup of tags if one hovers or scrolls over them?

[image]

I already tried this question: [Option to disable tag hover popup](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77521/option-to-disable-tag-hover-popup) but after the restyling it does not seem to work anymore

Comment: If you use an AdBlocker, adding `https://*.stackexchange.com/tags/*/popup?_=*` works for me.

Comment: @rene Fantastic! That works very well. Would you like to convert this into an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that the TagPopup is delay loaded by making an Ajax call to

> [`https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/feature-request/popup`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/feature-request/popup)

when you hover over the div with the tag.

If your browser is able to block specific urls (or you have an AdBlocker plugin like [uBlock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UBlock_Origin)), you can block

> `https://*.stackexchange.com/tags/*/popup?_=*`

and that prevents the GET request to complete. The errors are silently ignored.

Alternatively you could create an userscript that leverages an [jQuery ajaxSetup](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/) call to block the specific tags/[your tag here]/popup:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ 
  beforeSend: (xhr, opt)=> { 
    return (/^\/tags\/.+\/popup\?_=\d+$/gm).exec(opt.url) === null
  }
});
```